# NullPointerException: fav_up_btn1 = null

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm getting an error stating:

```
NullPointerException at com.idg.omv.ui.phone.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:149)
```

I've done a bit of debugging and found that  fav_up_btn1 = null however I'm not sure exactly what is causing it. I have verified  fav_up_btn1 exists in my XML and I'm not sure exactly what else it might be.

### JAVA SNIPPET:

```
mainScrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.groupScrollView);

fav_up_btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fav_up_btn1);

fav_up_btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        boolean favIsUp = fav_up_btn1
                .getBackground()
                .getConstantState()
                .equals(getResources().getDrawable(
                        R.drawable.fav_up_btn1).getConstantState());
        // set the background
        fav_up_btn1
        .setBackgroundResource(favIsUp ? R.drawable.fav_dwn_btn1
                : R.drawable.fav_up_btn1);
```

### XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <!-- The main content view -->

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <!-- The navigation drawer -->

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#111"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" />

    <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
        android:id="@+id/youtubeplayerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <com.idg.omv.ui.widget.VideosListView
        android:id="@+id/videosListView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dip"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/groupScrollView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/selstation_up_btn"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="@color/darkgrey"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/selstation_up_btn" />
        </ScrollView>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:src="@drawable/scroll_lt_arrow" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:src="@drawable/fav_up_btn1" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:src="@drawable/scroll_rt_arrow" />

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/view_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

### FULL JAVA SOURCE:

```
public class MainActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements
YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener,
YouTubeThumbnailView.OnInitializedListener {
    // A reference to our list that will hold the video details
    private VideosListView listView;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    public static final String API_KEY = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    public static final String VIDEO_ID = "o7VVHhK9zf0";
    public static final String VIDEO1_ID = "xVHHJqntuXI";
    public static final String VIDEO2_ID = "YWteQj_q3Ro";
    public static final String VIDEO3_ID = "83ZgtqTw-mI";
    public static final String VIDEO4_ID = "n5wMza29JwI";
    private YouTubeThumbnailLoader youTubeThumbnailLoader;
    private YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView1;
    private YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView2;
    private YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView3;
    private YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView4;
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private ListView drawerListView;
    private String[] drawerListViewItems;
    ScrollView mainScrollView;
    Button fav_up_btn1;
    Button fav_dwn_btn1;
    private YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView;
    String TAG = "DEBUG THIS";
    private YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
//         if(actionBar == null) {
//                 Log.i(TAG, "ActionBar is null");
//         } else {
//                 Log.i(TAG, "ActionBat is not null");

        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        ImagePagerAdapter adapter = new ImagePagerAdapter();
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        //final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar_custom_view_home);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        if(actionBar == null) { Log.i(TAG,"ActonBar is null");
        } else { 
            Log.i(TAG,"ActionBar is not null");};

        Bitmap d = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),
                R.drawable.selstation_up_btn);
        ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.selstation_up_btn);
        imgView.setImageBitmap(d);

        // get list items from strings.xml
        drawerListViewItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.items);

        // get ListView defined in activity_main.xml
        drawerListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

        // Set the adapter for the list view
        drawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.drawer_listview_item, drawerListViewItems));

        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, /* host Activity */
                drawerLayout, /* DrawerLayout object */
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, /* nav drawer icon to replace 'Up' caret */
                R.string.drawer_open, /* "open drawer" description */
                R.string.drawer_close /* "close drawer" description */
                );
        drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);

        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        drawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow,
                GravityCompat.START);

        youTubePlayerView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtubeplayerview);
        youTubePlayerView.initialize(API_KEY, this);

        mainScrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.groupScrollView);

//      youTubeThumbnailView1 = (YouTubeThumbnailView) findViewById(R.id.youtubethumbnailview1);
//      youTubeThumbnailView1.initialize(API_KEY, this);

        fav_up_btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fav_up_btn1);

        fav_up_btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                boolean favIsUp = fav_up_btn1
                        .getBackground()
                        .getConstantState()
                        .equals(getResources().getDrawable(
                                R.drawable.fav_up_btn1).getConstantState());
                // set the background
                fav_up_btn1
                .setBackgroundResource(favIsUp ? R.drawable.fav_dwn_btn1
                        : R.drawable.fav_up_btn1);
            }
        });

        youTubeThumbnailView1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                if (youTubePlayer != null) {
                    youTubePlayer.cueVideo(VIDEO1_ID);
                    youTubePlayer.play();
                    mainScrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, 0);
                }
            }
        });

        youTubeThumbnailView2 = (YouTubeThumbnailView) findViewById(R.id.youtubethumbnailview2);
        youTubeThumbnailView2.initialize(API_KEY, this);

        youTubeThumbnailView2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg1) {
                if (youTubePlayer != null) {
                    youTubePlayer.cueVideo(VIDEO2_ID);
                    youTubePlayer.play();
                    mainScrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, 0);
                }
            }
        });

        youTubeThumbnailView3 = (YouTubeThumbnailView) findViewById(R.id.youtubethumbnailview3);
        youTubeThumbnailView3.initialize(API_KEY, this);

        youTubeThumbnailView3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg1) {
                if (youTubePlayer != null) {
                    youTubePlayer.cueVideo(VIDEO3_ID);
                    youTubePlayer.play();
                    mainScrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, 0);
                }
            }
        });

        youTubeThumbnailView4 = (YouTubeThumbnailView) findViewById(R.id.youtubethumbnailview4);
        youTubeThumbnailView4.initialize(API_KEY, this);

        youTubeThumbnailView4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg1) {
                if (youTubePlayer != null) {
                    youTubePlayer.cueVideo(VIDEO4_ID);
                    youTubePlayer.play();
                    mainScrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, 0);
                }
            }

        });}



    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(Provider provider,
            YouTubeInitializationResult result) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider,
            YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {

        youTubePlayer = player;

        if (!wasRestored) {
            player.cueVideo(VIDEO_ID);

        }
    }


    public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubeThumbnailView thumbnailView,
            YouTubeInitializationResult error) {

    }


    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubeThumbnailView thumbnailView,
            YouTubeThumbnailLoader thumbnailLoader) {

        youTubeThumbnailLoader = thumbnailLoader;
        thumbnailLoader
        .setOnThumbnailLoadedListener(new ThumbnailLoadedListener());

        youTubeThumbnailLoader.setVideo(VIDEO_ID);

    }

    private final class ThumbnailLoadedListener implements
    YouTubeThumbnailLoader.OnThumbnailLoadedListener {

        @Override
        public void onThumbnailError(YouTubeThumbnailView arg0, ErrorReason arg1) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onThumbnailLoaded(YouTubeThumbnailView arg0, String arg1) {

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        actionBarDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        // call ActionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(), if it returns
        // true
        // then it has handled the app icon touch event
        if (actionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
        private int[] mImages = new int[] { R.drawable.classical_up_btn,
                R.drawable.country_up_btn, R.drawable.dance_up_btn,
                R.drawable.hiphop_up_btn };

        public int getCount() {
            return mImages.length;
        }

        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            return view == ((ImageView) object);
        }

        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            Context context = MainActivity.this;
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
            int padding = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(
                    R.dimen.padding_medium);
            imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            imageView.setImageResource(mImages[position]);
            ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
            return imageView;
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show your MainActivity class.

Comment: I just posted a snippet - let me know if more detail is needed.

Comment: probably you didn't set your content view. Before calling a button with its id. setLayoutContentView(yourLayoutId). If you put your oncreate methot it will be easier to detect problem

Comment: I did set my contentview (I updated my post with the complete code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you should add this to your button (look the second line).

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/fav_up_btn1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:src="@drawable/fav_up_btn1" />
```

In your code, you didn't provide any id with fav_up_btn1, so when you tried to get the view with this id, it failed